# If repeaters/hubs are connected into a loop, rather than bridges, what happens when somebody transmits?

Tags: networking, bridge, hub

On a network, repeaters(hubs) are connected into a loop, instead of using bridges. What happens when a transmission is made?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that packets could circulate the network endlessly. The spanning tree protocol is used to prevent that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of hubs with loops is slightly different than switches.  See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_hub#Uses and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier_sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection

If a switch has a loop.  The first broadcast packet that comes in will go out then come back in then go out,in,out,in and get multiplied an infinite number of times.  This will kill the entire LAN if other protections are not in place (some switches have limits on broadcast packets, etc.)

If a hub has a loop any thing you try and send into it immediately collides and every device that is connected to it sees the collision and will not transmit into the hub for the backoff period.  So nothing that goes into a looped hub ever comes out.  If a looped hub is connected to another hub that hub will also not work but if a looped hub is connected to a switch it will not effect the other ports on the switch.  If you have a mixture of switches an hubs a looped hub will not bring down the entire LAN.